# Customize how links are opened

Tags: javascript

The code below retrieves a list of links from a javascript generated url (http://us1.campaign-archive2.com/generate-js/?u=37e5f50ea5a65008de12f2e48&fid=47053&show=10)

Is there a way using the code below to have the links open in a frame on the same page, rather than in a new tab?

```
<style type="text/css">

<!--
.display_archive {font-family: arial,verdana; font-size: 12px;}
.campaign {line-height: 125%; margin: 5px;}
//-->
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="http://us1.campaign-archive2.com/generate-js/?u=37e5f50ea5a65008de12f2e48&fid=47053&show=10" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript's `widow.open()` `onclick`. You can leave off the window, since it's implicit, like `open()`. Use the third argument to set the specs. Note that you should `return false` `onclick` if you are using actual links because they will redirect according to their target, otherwise

Comment: this opens it in a new window. i would like the links from the website http://us1.campaign-archive2.com/generate-js/?u=37e5f50ea5a65008de12f2e48&fid=47053&show=10 to all show on a webpage in iFrames, like a portfolio of each page on t

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `target="_blank"` attribute from `<a>` tag.

Now the page has all links in the format like:

```
 <a href="http://..." title="Anything" to="" celebrate="" ?="" 
    find="" the="" right="" location="" 
    target="_blank">
       Anything to Celebrate ? Find the right Location
 </a>
```

If you remove `target` attribute, all links will open in the same window.

To open url from JavaScript simply use:

```
location.href = "http://...";
```

By default browser opens new url in the same window.